# What is the purpose of decimation when calibrating a camera with Charuco?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration, aruco

I have been working on performing camera calibration using [ChAruCo boards](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d4a/tutorial_charuco_detection.html).

Following the code [here](https://mecaruco2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks_rst/Aruco/sandbox/ludovic/aruco_calibration_rotation.html) (my commented version is shown below), it appears that only every other image is used when performing the camera calibration - due to the decimator.

What could be a reason for this? Other than to save processing power, which seems unnecessary since this step is only performed once.

```
def read_chessboards(chessboard_images):
# Charuco base pose estimation.

print("POSE ESTIMATION STARTS:")

# Declare lists to store corner locations and IDs
allCorners = []
allIds = []
decimator = 0

# SUB PIXEL CORNER DETECTION CRITERION
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.00001)

# for each of the chessboard images
for im in chessboard_images:
    print("=> Processing image {0}".format(im))
    frame = cv2.imread(im)                          # read current image into frame variable
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # convert to grayscale
    corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(gray, ARUCO_DICT)  # detect markers present in image

    # if there are any markers detected
    if len(corners) > 0:
        # SUB PIXEL DETECTION
        for corner in corners:
            # refine corner locations
            # TODO: check if this works
            cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corner,
                             winSize=(3, 3),
                             zeroZone=(-1, -1),
                             criteria=criteria)

        # interpolate position of ChArUco board corners.
        res2 = cv2.aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco(corners, ids, gray, board)
        print(f'Charuco corners at: {res2}')

        # if 3+ corners are detected, add to allCorners list for every other image
        if res2[1] is not None and res2[2] is not None and len(res2[1]) > 3 and decimator % 1 == 0:
            allCorners.append(res2[1])
            allIds.append(res2[2])

    # why only every other chessboard image?
    decimator += 1

imsize = gray.shape
return allCorners, allIds, imsize
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that x % 1 always evaluates to 0, so it doesn't actually do anything. I guess it was included as an optional feature - if you change 1 to some other number.